# Turning off pppoe

Tags: dhcp, pppoe

I had a pppoe connection and I am trying now to connect to another network without pppoe. I've made the following modifications in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
################################
auto lo    
iface lo inet loopback    
# auto dsl-provider    
# iface dsl-provider inet ppp    
# pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf    
# provider dsl-provider  

auto eth0    
iface eth0 inet dhcp    
################################
```

Also, a have deleted the `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider` file.

Now, I am unable to restart the network service with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and the booting of the system takes me up to 5 minutes.

Please help. :)
Thank you.

PS: I've figured it out. I had the dhcp turned off. I used `sudo dhclient eth0`.

Comment: Are you sure that the network you want to connect offers you a DHCP server? Maybe you need to usea static network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're editing the wrong file or if it's just a typo in your question, but you should be editing `/etc/init.d/networking`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using this `sudo poff`? If not, running that command may solve your problem.